# relationship between "linear approximation" to immersions and formal immersions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, h-principle

I'm reading [these notes](http://math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/classes/hprin/1overview.pdf)

Here, I am regarding $\mathrm{Imm}(-,N)$ as a presheaf on the open sets of some manifold $M$

If we take $\mathrm{Imm}^f(-,N)$ to be the sheaf of formal immersion (an element is an injective bundle map on the tangent bundles covering an arbitrary map $g:M \to N$.)

I've gathered from context that there is a connection between formal immersions and the sheaf of sections  $\mathcal{F}(U):=\Gamma(V_n(TU) \times_{GL_n} \mathrm{Imm}(\mathbb R^n,N))$ (defined for an arbitrary open $\mathbb R^n \to M$. Please see definition 3.2  and the preceeding paragraph in the linked notes for more details.) This is referenced as the linear approximation to the sheaf of immersions, but I don't know why, although I assume it agrees in the sense of functor calculus.

**My questions are the following**: is the topological sheaf of formal immersions isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$? If not, is there some relationship? If so, is the scanning map of Segal compatible (via some isomorphism) with the ``obvious" maps $\mathrm{Imm}(U,N) \to \mathrm{Imm}^f(U,N),\,\,\, f \mapsto (df,f)$?

Comment: The last obvious map is 1-jet prolongation. The basic motivation here is to realize Hirsch-Smale as an instance of the H-principle in the sense of the posted notes (via the scanning map)

Comment: I think the idea is that we can view a formal immersion as immersing a neighborhood of p into the tangent space of $g(p)$. This coincides with how we view the linearization of a diff invariant sheaf because the fiber over a point of the linearization is a colimit of the sheaf on values of trivial neighborhoods, and these trivial neighborhoods are exactly what the tangent space approximates via the exponential map (which we use to define the scanning map).

Comment: @ConnorMalin thank you for your comment, it was very helpful! What remains for me is writing down an explicit map (and hopefully it’s inverse.) I will try to work it out later today using your insights.

Comment: You probably need to choose a type of exponential map to define the isomorphism. Probably a good idea to choose this so it coincides with the exponential used to define the scanning map if you want the square to commute.

Comment: Check out section 37 of these notes: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~kupers/teaching/272x/book.pdf . To be linear (at a manifold) is to have the map to the first taylor approximation a weak equivalence. It seems to me after reading this that satisfying the h-principle is equivalent to being linear.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I think one needs "h-principle+reduced=linear" if I remember the terminology correctly. I agree. I think my confusion here is why hirsch-smale is an h-principle a lot. I will look at those notes (which I've used in the past to some success for different topics.) Thanks!\

Comment: @ConnorMalin sorry for the late update. I think that this settles why being "linear"+reduced is equivalent to satisfying an $h$-principle in the sense of the notes I posted. The exposition here did not have enough detail for me to compute why $F(U)$ is actually (as above) is $T_1(Imm(U))$. In particular, I don't understand how the "bousfield-kan formula" gives what Kupers claims, or even assuming that, why it results in the formula that he writes. Another thing (which is basically what this question is about) is why the natural map $Imm(U) \to F(U)$ being a homotopy equivalence...

Comment: is an equivalent condition to $Imm(U) \hookrightarrow Imm^f(U)$ being a homotopy equivalence.